# Sending errors to apollo graphql

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a query resolver like this:

```
page: (root, args) =>
      DB.page
        .findById(args.id)
        .then((result) => {
          if (result == null) throw Error(`Page not found for ${args.id}`);
          return result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          log.error('Error in page query.', error.message);
        }),
```

When I execute the query, the result is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "page": null
  }
}
```

But it's not showing the error that I've thrown when the query fail. 
What I expect:

```
{
  "errors": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're catching the error right after it's thrown. You'll need to either omit the `catch` altogether, or throw the caught error after logging it:

```
.catch((error) => {
  log.error('Error in page query.', error.message)
  throw error
}),
```